# How to test a single docstring using pytest --doctest-modules?

Tags: python, pytest, doctest

I know that a single test using pytest can be achieved using `pytest test.py::test_single`.  Is there a similar method for choosing a single docstring test to run using `pytest --doctest-modules mymodule.py`?  This doesn't work: `pytest --doctest-modules mymodule.py::MyClass.foo`.

For example:

```py
# mymodule.py
class MyClass:
    """
    My Class.

    >>> print("Some testing here")
    Some testing here
    """

    def foo(self):
        """
        Print foo.

        >>> myclass = MyClass()
        >>> myclass.foo()
        foo
        """
        print("foo")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use the module name in the test name `pytest --doctest-modules mymodule.py::mymodule.MyClass.foo`.

### Full Answer

Using `pytest --doctest-modules -v mymodule.py` provides the necessary information to determine how to selectively run tests.

Expanding the example from the Question to contrast with other types of pytest tests:

```py
# mymodule.py
class MyClass:
    """
    My Class.

    >>> print("Some testing here")
    Some testing here
    """

    def foo(self):
        """
        Print foo.

        >>> myclass = MyClass()
        >>> myclass.foo()
        foo
        """
        print("foo")


class TestClass:
    def test_inside_class(self):
        assert True


def test_normal_test():
    assert True
```

Running `pytest --doctest-modules -v mymodule.py` shows the name of the tests as collected by pytest.

```
collected 4 items                                                                   

mymodule.py::mymodule.MyClass PASSED                                          [ 25%]
mymodule.py::mymodule.MyClass.foo PASSED                                      [ 50%]
mymodule.py::TestClass::test_inside_class PASSED                              [ 75%]
mymodule.py::test_normal_test PASSED                                          [100%]
```

Note that the doctests names have a different format depending on the type of test collected.  Tests collected from doctests additionally have the module name.

If we run `pytest --doctest-modules mymodule.py::mymodule.MyClass.foo -v`, it will run only the desired test:

```
collected 1 item                                                                    

mymodule.py::mymodule.MyClass.foo PASSED                                      [100%]
```